# How to draw a path with gradient on NET Maui app?

Tags: .net, maui

Looking at the `GraphicsView` examples created by MAUI creators:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/GraphicsViewDemos

you can find some `GraphicsView` examples, and specially an example that shows how to draw a reactangle with gradient (vertical, horizontal, etc..)

```
internal class VerticalLinearGradientPaintDrawable : IDrawable
{
    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        LinearGradientPaint linearGradientPaint = new LinearGradientPaint
        {
            StartColor = Colors.Yellow,
            EndColor = Colors.Green,
            // StartPoint is already (0,0)
            EndPoint = new Point(0, 1)
        };

        RectF linearRectangle = new RectF(10, 10, 200, 100);
        canvas.SetFillPaint(linearGradientPaint, linearRectangle);
        canvas.SetShadow(new SizeF(10, 10), 10, Colors.Grey);
        canvas.FillRoundedRectangle(linearRectangle, 12);
    }
}
```

But how to draw a path for a specific path (or polygon area)? I can't find the way.

Thanks.

I tried to find a method to draw a polygon with gradient but have not found the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

Define in code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon() { WidthRequest=70,HeightRequest=80,Stroke=Colors.Transparent};
    PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
    points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
    points.Add(new Point(40, 10));
    points.Add(new Point(70, 80));
    points.Add(new Point(10, 50));
    polygon.Points = points;

    GradientStopCollection gradientStops = new GradientStopCollection();
    gradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(color: Colors.Yellow, offset: 0));
    gradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(color: Colors.Green, offset: 1));
    LinearGradientBrush linearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(gradientStops,startPoint:new Point(0,0),endPoint:new Point(1,0));
    
    polygon.Fill = linearGradientBrush;

    mystack.Children.Add(polygon);
```

---

You could try using a [Linear gradient brushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/lineargradient) and [Polygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/shapes/polygon)
. Consider the following code:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
    <Polygon Points="0,0 40,10 70,80 10,50"
         Stroke="Transparent"
         StrokeThickness="5" >
            <Polygon.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />                  
                    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Polygon.Fill>
    </Polygon>
</StackLayout>
```

**Vertical linear gradient** result (EndPoint="0,1"):

[image]

**Horizontal linear gradient** (EndPoint="1,0"):

[image]

**Diagonal linear gradient** (EndPoint="1,1"):

[image]

Hope it helps.